# C++: Creating an object in a method and using it outside of method

Tags: c++

The code is pretty straight forward:

```
class SuperClass
{
public:
    virtual void someMethod() = 0;
};

class SubClass : public SuperClass
{
public:
    virtual void someMethod()
    {
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    }
};

class CallerClass
{
public:
    std::vector<SuperClass*> subClasses;

    CallerClass()
    {
        subClasses.push_back(&SubClass());
    }

    void callMethods()
    {
        subClasses[0]->someMethod();
    }
};

int main(int argx, char**argv)
{
    CallerClass cc;
    cc.callMethods();

    return 0;
}
```

The problem occurs when I actually call try to call the subClass' 'someMethod()' in the CallerClass' 'callMethods()'. In Visual Studio, it simply breaks at that line of code without any explanation. I have solved the problem by changing     push_back(&SubClass())     to    push_back(new SubClass()).

I am curious as to why the latter works and not the former. I thought it was because an object created in a method will only exist within the method, and by using 'new', space was actually being allocated for that object after the function ended; but I added an    int a = 1    to SuperClass and was able to access it using in a similar fashion to what's inside 'callMethods()'.

I must be missing some fundamental aspect of C++ here. Please inform me. Hopefully it's not something too obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
subClasses.push_back(&SubClass());
```

You are storing a pointer to a temporary object, which is destroyed just after.

Then, when you call someMethod, you are calling a method on an invalid object pointer which was already deleted.

With

```
subClasses.push_back(new SubClass());
```

You are storing a pointer to a valid object, so it works.

Comment: Then why when I make an 'int a = 1' in the SuperClass and call it the same why, it works?

Comment: @user3584262 because of Undefined Behavior. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/367662/3301533

Comment: Yes. By undefined behavior, the C++ standard don't guarantees you a crash. It just tells you that anything might happen because you did it wrong.

Comment: This answers the question but I think any considerate answer should  point out that using `new` will result in a memory leak and provide some sort of advice on how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you do `push_back(&SubClass())` you are adding a pointer to the vector that points to a temporary object. At the end of the expression the temporary object will be deleted. When you call `callMethods` you are dereferencing a pointer to a deleted object. This is undefined behaviour, anything could happen, it could even work!

By calling `push_back(new SubClass());` you are allocating an object on the heap and adding a pointer to that object to the vector. This object on the heap will not be deleted when the expression ends.

In fact this object will not be deleted at all and would be a memory leak in your program. `CallerClass` effectively owns the objects so it is its responsibility to delete them when it is done.

To fix the memory leak there are a couple of changes you need to make. You need to add a public virtual destructor to `SuperClass`:

```
virtual ~SuperClass(){};
```

This ensures that if you call the destructor on `SuperClass` the `SubClass` will also be destroyed properly. Then you need to ensure that `delete` is called in the `CallerClass` destructor. You could do that by explicitly writing a destructor, looping over the elements of the vector and calling `delete` but the easier, C++11 way, is to use smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr`. If you change your vector to:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SuperClass>> subClasses;
```

then the objects will be automatically deleted in the `CallerClass` destructor and you don't have to explicitly write a destructor at all.

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/a5E9MO1G7bVeGIgx)</kbd>